# Spring @Requestbody serialize Array of Arrays (Coordinates)

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

My RestController method

```java
    @PostMapping(value = "/search/spatial", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Point>> findSpatialResults(@RequestBody List<Point> points) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(points);
    }
```

receives the **coordinates of a polygon/multipolygon** in the form

```json
[
    [
        144.66796875000003,
        -23.21549308957186
    ],
    ...
    [
        144.39629254087737,
        -23.290953516004656
    ],
]
```

Because my coordinates are not objects, like

```
 [{
        "x": 144.66796875000003,
        "y": -23.21549308957186
 }]
```

Jackson failes to map them (*Cannot deserialize instance of `java.awt.Point` out of START_ARRAY token*)

**How to serialize the Array of Arrays to, for example, a `ArrayList<Point>`?**

Comment: You'll need a customer deserializer, see https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization if you're using Jackson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating custom deserializer is one way to go, and another is to do it by hand like so:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/search/spatial", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<List<Point>> findSpatialResults(@RequestBody List<List<Integer>> points) {
    List<Point> parsedPoints = points.stream().map(it -> new Point(it.get(0), it.get(1))).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return ResponseEntity.ok(parsedPoints);
}
```

For input

```
[
    [
        144,
        -23
    ],
    [
        144,
        -23
    ]
]
```

produces result

```
[
    {
        "x": 144.0,
        "y": -23.0
    },
    {
        "x": 144.0,
        "y": -23.0
    }
]
```

**EDIT:** Simple deserializer for `java.awt.Point` from array of doubles (it lacks proper error handling):

```
public class PointDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Point> {

    @Override
    public Point deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectCodec oc = jp.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jp);

        ArrayNode arrayNode = (ArrayNode) node;
        double x = arrayNode.get(0).doubleValue();
        double y = arrayNode.get(1).doubleValue();

        return new Point((int) x, (int) y);
    }
}
```

Then, if you use Spring, we should register this deserializer like so:

```
@Bean
public Module pointDeserializer() {
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addDeserializer(Point.class, new PointDeserializer());
    return module;
}
```

And controller will parse correctly `List<Point>`:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/search/spatial", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<List<Point>> findSpatialResults(@RequestBody List<Point> points) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(points);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this fast & easy solution, although I'd change Integer -> Double for the coordinates. Do you have further information on how to create the `List<List<Integer>>` from the @RequestBody mapping in a Jackson custom deserializer? I cannot figure out how the tokenizer works for unnamed JSON params.
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization

Comment: @nonNumericalFloat I've updated my answer with deserializer

Comment: Thank you for the generous explanation! I was  the cast `Node` to a `ArrayNode`. So I guess the Point is the only thing which needs the custom deserializer and the `List` itself get deserialized by the default Jackson stuff?

Comment: yes, we need only deserializer for `Point` and jackson is clever enough to use it to parse `List<Point>`